# How to use changes in values in one dataframe column to calculate another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, percentage, calculated-columns

Lets say I have a dataframe.
The first column is positive numbers, call it PRICE.

The values in the second column, call it MORELESS, can only be 1, or -1 and are calculated based on whether the value of PRICE in the current row is more than (1) or less than (-1) the value of price in the previous row.

This part I can code OK.

Now, the third column, called CHANGE is more difficult.

CHANGE doesnt necessarily have a value in every row, and is calculated only when MORELESS changes (from 1 to -1 or -1 to 1). It is the percentage change in VALUE between the current row and the last row where a CHANGE happened (ie wherever MORELESS changes 1/-1, -1/1). Heres an example I did by hand in excel:

| INDEX | PRICE | MORELESS | CHANGE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 148,25 |  |  |
| 2 | 143,53 | -1 | -3,18 |
| 3 | 139,94 | -1 |  |
| 4 | 139,00 | -1 |  |
| 5 | 140,31 | 1 | -2,24 |
| 6 | 146,25 | 1 |  |
| 7 | 145,81 | -1 | 3,92 |
| 8 | 144,59 | -1 |  |
| 9 | 144,47 | -1 |  |
| 10 | 146,53 | 1 | 0,49 |
| 11 | 145,34 | -1 | -0,81 |
| 12 | 145,31 | -1 |  |
| 13 | 146,97 | 1 | 1,12 |
| 14 | 145,50 | -1 | -1,00 |
| 15 | 145,66 | 1 | 0,11 |
| 16 | 140,52 | -1 | -3,53 |
| 17 | 141,00 | 1 | 0,34 |
| 18 | 141,84 | 1 |  |
| 19 | 139,44 | -1 | -1,11 |
| 20 | 135,81 | -1 |  |
| 21 | 139,75 | 1 | 0,22 |
| 22 | 141,28 | 1 |  |

Examples:
CHANGE in row 11 uses PRICE in row 10: 100*(145.34-146.53)/146.53
CHANGE in row 21 uses PRICE in row 19: 100*(139.75-139.44)/139.44

What would be the best way to code the CHANGE column?

Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve].
In particular your question is ways too verbose and long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made a `'cs'` column by which you can `group.`
To get it, I compared the values of the `'MORELESS'` column with its shifted value. Transformed
to type int, giving 1, where True. Then calculated the `cumulative sum`.

In `split` I get the `index` of the next after row `where 'cs' == 1` to use the slice when grouping. In `'aaa'` I get the index of the ferst row with the previous `'cs'.`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df['cs'] = (df['MORELESS'] != df['MORELESS'].shift()).astype(int).cumsum()
split = df[df['cs'] == 1].index[-1] + 1
df['test'] = np.nan


def my_func(x):
    aaa = df[df['cs'] == x['cs'].values[0] - 1].index[0]
    df.loc[x.index[0], 'test'] = 100 * ((df.loc[x.index[0], 'PRICE'] - df.loc[aaa, 'PRICE']) / df.loc[aaa, 'PRICE'])


df[split:].groupby('cs').apply(my_func)

print(df)
```

Output

```
    INDEX   PRICE  MORELESS  CHANGE  cs      test
0       1  148.25       NaN     NaN   1       NaN
1       2  143.53      -1.0   -3.18   2 -3.183811
2       3  139.94      -1.0     NaN   2       NaN
3       4  139.00      -1.0     NaN   2       NaN
4       5  140.31       1.0   -2.24   3 -2.243433
5       6  146.25       1.0     NaN   3       NaN
6       7  145.81      -1.0    3.92   4  3.919892
7       8  144.59      -1.0     NaN   4       NaN
8       9  144.47      -1.0     NaN   4       NaN
9      10  146.53       1.0    0.49   5  0.493793
10     11  145.34      -1.0   -0.81   6 -0.812120
11     12  145.31      -1.0     NaN   6       NaN
12     13  146.97       1.0    1.12   7  1.121508
13     14  145.50      -1.0   -1.00   8 -1.000204
14     15  145.66       1.0    0.11   9  0.109966
15     16  140.52      -1.0   -3.53  10 -3.528766
16     17  141.00       1.0    0.34  11  0.341588
17     18  141.84       1.0     NaN  11       NaN
18     19  139.44      -1.0   -1.11  12 -1.106383
19     20  135.81      -1.0     NaN  12       NaN
20     21  139.75       1.0    0.22  13  0.222318
21     22  141.28       1.0     NaN  13       NaN
```

Comment: Wow. Im going to have to study that in detail! Many thanks for the support!

Comment: If you have any questions, please ask. You can upvote the answer if it helped you.

Comment: OK Will do. Still learning how to use the site.